# Initializing the quantity

Tags: java, android

I want that when my app starts, it shows 2 as the initial quantity. It always shows 0. What should I do?

```
 /**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int quantity = 2;

    displayPrice (quantity * 5);
}



/**
 * This method is called when plus button is clicked.
 */

public void increment(View view) {
    int quantity = 2;
    quantity = quantity + 1;

    display(quantity);

}
/**
 * This method is called when minus button is clicked.
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    int quantity = 1;
    display (quantity);
}
```

[image]

Comment: in `onCreate` after reference initialization put `yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(2));`

Comment: set static value, as 2

Comment: the piece of code you add to your post is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either invoke `display(2);` in your Activity's `onCreate` method or edit the xml layout so that the value of your quantitiy TextView is 2 by default.